# Multicolumn problem

Tags: multicolumn

I'm trying to have a series of titles using `\multicolumn`, but I'm systematically having the error "Missing `\cr` inserted." when I try to run the code below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table} [!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c  c  c  c}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Title}} \\
1 & 2  & 3 & 4 \\ \hline    
\end{tabular}
\newline
\caption{caption of table}  \label{tab:table7_2}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
 \multicolumn{4}{c}{Title}} \\
```

should be

```
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Title} \\ %one } removed
```

Comment: Awesome! It works now!

Thanks a lot, Przemyslaw!